# BLE Explorer for Windows 10 Universal

Tags: windows-8.1, windows-10-universal, bluetooth-lowenergy

Is there any Bluetooth Low Energy sample applications for Windows 10 universal platform? Please help me.

Answer (score 1):

[Bluetooth GATT](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/devices-sensors/gatt-scenarios) is for BLE on UWP apps. There are sample code in the official document for three common GATT scenarios: retrieving Bluetooth data, controlling a Bluetooth LE thermometer device, and controlling the presentation of Bluetooth LE device data.

Besides, you can also refer to the [BLE GATT Sample for Iot](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/iot/win10/samples/blegatt2).

Though these are all official information about using BLE for UWP apps, I believe there are also many samples on internet written by other developers, you can search for them.